# Rails set basic http Auth Credentials programatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, password|
      user == USER && password == PASSWORD
    end
```

The above code asks for a username and password in a regular fashion (using basic_http_auth)

My idea was to create a user login page , some how check the username & password to be valid and then authenticate him.
Now `authenticate him` means to create a header that would have been sent by browser if he  was actually authenticated via basic_http_auth . i.e to set the simple http auth credentials

The requirement is so because there is another non ruby app that would run on the same domain internally & would check if the user is authenticated via simple_http_auth.

The over all picture would be something like this :
Rails app : authenticates user.
The second non ruby app just checks if the user is authenticated since its under the same domin it can simply access the user_name password send via http_basic auth.

The other idea is to run a rails api service that would determine if the user is logged in or not , and call it via the second app. But I don't prefer doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Gaurav  you should try to set your default username and password values with default http setting in "config/initializers " folder inside setup_mail.rb file

Comment: That is for mail configuration .. I am talking about basic_http_auth